# How to restore / reset window.console.log

Tags: javascript

I have an application that changes window.console.log to a function.

I want to reset window.console.log back it normal on a certain page, however when I run `delete window.console.log;` and call console.log('asd'); I get an exception

`TypeError: console.log is not a function. (In 'console.log(error)', 'console.log' is undefined)`

How do I restore it properly so a certain page can simply console.log normally instead of the custom one I had?

Comment: Are you able to access the code from before the `console.log` function was modified by the application?

Comment: @Patrick yes, it was printing fine before the custom function

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to access the code from before the application modifies `console.log` you could do the following:

```js
window.defaultConsoleLog = console.log;

// here would be the code where the application modifies console.log

// calling console.log would now be the modified version from the application:
console.log('Hello');

// calling defaultConsoleLog would now call the original console.log:
defaultConsoleLog.log('Hello');
// OR
window.defaultConsoleLog('Hello');

// you can then reset to the original console.log like this:
console.log = window.defaultConsoleLog;
```

When you were doing `delete window.console.log`, this removes the function from the `window.console` object instead of resetting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the old native function in an other variable or property and restore it later. For example :

```js
// Storing the native console.log into a property in window
window.oldLog = window.console.log

// Overriding the console.log function
console.log = (str) => { document.getElementById('logs').textContent += str }

console.log('Calling the new console.log')
window.oldLog('Calling the old console.log')

// Now resetting the native console.log
console.log = window.oldLog

// Clearing up
delete window.oldLog

console.log('Calling the restored console.log')
```

```html
<pre id="logs"></pre>
```